# How to handle multiple optionals in grammar

Tags: rascal

I would like to know how I can handle multiple optionals without concrete pattern matching for each possible permutation.

Below is a simplified example of the problem I am facing:

```
lexical Int = [0-9]+;
syntax Bool = "True" | "False";
syntax Period = "Day" | "Month" | "Quarter" | "Year";
layout Standard = [\ \t\n\f\r]*; 
syntax Optionals = Int? i Bool? b Period? p;

str printOptionals(Optionals opt){
    str res = "";
    if(!isEmpty("<opt.i>")) { // opt has i is always true (same for opt.i?)
        res += printInt(opt.i);
    }
    if(!isEmpty("<opt.b>")){
        res += printBool(opt.b);
    }
    if(!isEmpty("<opt.p>")) {
        res += printPeriod(opt.period);
    }
    return res;
}

str printInt(Int i) = "<i>";
str printBool(Bool b) = "<b>";
str printPeriod(Period p) = "<p>";
```

However this gives the error message:

```
The called signature: printInt(opt(lex("Int"))), does not match the declared signature: str printInt(sort("Int"));
```

How do I get rid of the opt part when I know it is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how ideal this is, but you could do this for now:

```
if (/Int i := opt.i) {
    res += printInt(i);
}
```

This will extract the `Int` from within `opt.i` if it is there, but the match will fail if `Int` was not provided as one of the options.

Answer (score 1):

The current master on github has the following feature to deal with optionals: they can be iterated over.

For example:

```
if (Int i <- opt.i) {
    res += printInt(i);
}
```

The `<-` will produce `false` immediately if the optional value is absent, and otherwise loop once through and bind the value which is present to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

An untyped solution is to project out the element from the parse tree:

```
rascal>opt.i.args[0];
Tree: `1`
Tree: appl(prod(lex("Int"),[iter(\char-class([range(48,57)]))],{}),[appl(regular(iter(\char-class([range(48,57)]))),[char(49)])[@loc=|file://-|(0,1,<1,0>,<1,1>)]])[@loc=|file://-|(0,1,<1,0>,<1,1>)]
```

However, then to transfer this back to an `Int` you'd have to pattern match, like so:

```
rascal>if (Int i := opt.i.args[0]) { printInt(i); }
str: "1"
```

One could write a generic cast function to help out here:

```
rascal>&T cast(type[&T] t, value v) { if (&T a := v) return a; throw "cast exception"; }
ok
rascal>printInt(cast(#Int, opt.i.args[0]))
str: "1"
```

Still, I believe Rascal is missing a feature here. Something like this would be a good feature request:

```
rascal>Int j = opt.i.value;
rascal>opt.i has value
bool: true
```